# How to expand an absolutely positioned list

Tags: css, navigation, absolute

Is it possible to tell an absolutely positioned list item to push the next list item down? https://jsfiddle.net/230cfs4g/
In this example, the list items under Sub-Menu overlap the links under it.

My goal is for it to push the other links UNDER it down, similar to how the mobile version (included) functions, whilst still maintaining the hover over the content aspect that you expect from a desktop menu..

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<nav>
   <div class="nav-menu">
      <div class="menu-navmenu-container">
         <ul id="menu-navmenu" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-3499" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3499"><a href="=">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3855" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-3855 menu-item-with-children">
               <a>Services</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-4498" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4498 menu-item-with-children">
                     <a href="">SubMenu</a>
                     <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-3664" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3664"><a href="=">Link</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-4339" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4339 menu-item-with-children">
                           <a href="=">Link</a>
                           <ul class="sub-menu">
                              <li id="menu-item-3497" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3497"><a href="=">Link</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-3529" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3529"><a href="=">Link</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-4219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4219"><a href="=">Link</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-3585" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3585"><a href="=">Link</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

````
body {
  background-color: #191919;}
a {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
p {color: #fff;}
.menu-item-with-children > a::after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f078";
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.sub-menu  {
  display: none;
}
.active {display: block;}


.menu {
  background-color: white;
  white-space:nowrap;
 margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  
}
.menu-item {

}
.menu-item a {
  color: #666;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  color: #007bff;
  background-color: #cfe6ff;
}

.sub-menu {
  
padding-left: 20px;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
 }
.menu-item-with-children .active {
font-weight: bold;

}
.menu {background-color: #fff;}

.sub-menu.active {
  background-color: #fff;

}

.menu-item-with-children .active  li {
    border-left: 2px solid #c9c9c9;

  padding-left: 20px;
}

/*Desktop */

@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  .menu {
  display: flex;
    margin-top: 6px;
  }
  
  .menu-item {
  width: auto;
  }
  .menu-item a {
    font-size: 24px ;
    padding: 5px 25px 0 25px;
  }
 
  .sub-menu {
    position: fixed;
   padding: 0;
    min-width: 200px;

  }
  
 /*Trying to figure out how to get the list items to push the content down*/```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think it should not be absolutely positioned in this case. see this pleas.

```js
jQuery('.menu-item').each(function() {
  let _this = jQuery(this);
  if (_this.children('ul').length) {
    _this.addClass('menu-item-with-children');
  }

});
jQuery('.menu').on('click', '.menu-item > a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("active")) {
    jQuery(this).addClass('active')
    jQuery(this).next('ul').addClass('active')
    jQuery(this).children().addClass('active')
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().find('.active').removeClass('active')
      .parent().removeClass('active');
  }

  //Not sure why this works but what the hell.
  else if (jQuery(this).removeClass('active')) {
    jQuery(this).next('ul').removeClass('active')

    jQuery(this).children().removeClass('active')
    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('active').children().find('.active').removeClass('active').siblings().find('.active').removeClass('active')
      .parent().removeClass('active');
  } else {


    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('active').siblings().find('.active').removeClass('active').children().find('.active').removeClass('active')
      .parent().removeClass('active');
  }


  //Unused atm, may need lader
  //else if (jQuery(this).removeClass('active')){
  //jQuery(this).next('ul').removeClass('active')

  //      jQuery(this).children().removeClass('active')
  //jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('active').siblings().find('.active').removeClass('active')
  //.parent().removeClass('active');
  //     }


});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #191919;
}

a {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-item-with-children>a::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f078";
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  background-color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-item {}

.menu-item a {
  color: #666;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  color: #007bff;
  background-color: #cfe6ff;
}

.sub-menu {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu-item-with-children .active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sub-menu.active {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.menu-item-with-children .active li {
  border-left: 2px solid #c9c9c9;
  padding-left: 20px;
}


/*Desktop */

@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 6px;
  }
  .menu-item {
    width: auto;
  }
  .menu-item a {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 5px 25px 0 25px;
  }
  .sub-menu {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 200px;
  }
  /* Added this*/
  .sub-menu.nested {
    position: relative;
  }
}


/*Trying to figure out how to get the list items to push the content down*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<nav>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <div class="menu-navmenu-container">
      <ul id="menu-navmenu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-3499" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3499"><a href="=">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3855" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-3855 menu-item-with-children">
          <a>Services</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4498" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4498 menu-item-with-children">
              <a href="">SubMenu</a>
              
              <ul class="sub-menu nested">
                <li id="menu-item-3664" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3664"><a href="=">Link</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-4339" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4339 menu-item-with-children">
                  <a href="=">Link</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-3497" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3497"><a href="=">Link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-3529" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3529"><a href="=">Link</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-4219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4219"><a href="=">Link</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-3585" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3585"><a href="=">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<p>test</p>
```

Comment: So the reason why that one doesn't work is that it pops up on TOP of the submenu. I'm trying to figure out how to make it push the rest of the sub menu DOWN.

Answer (score 0):

`.sub-menu * {position: static;}`
is apparently the answer to all my problems.